# Access value of the variable in TCL

Tags: unit-testing, tcl

I have similar code for writing unit test where I need to check the value of a variable.

```
#first.tcl
proc test {a} {
   if {$a < 10} {
      set sig 0
   } else {
      set sig 1
   }
}
```

```
#second.tcl unit testing script
source "first.tcl"
test 10
expect 1 equal to $sig
test 5
expect 0 equal to $sig
```

Is there any way, that I can access the value of the variable "sig" as I can not change the first script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem. The problem is that in the first script, `sig` is a *local* variable that vanishes when the call to `test` terminates. You can't examine it afterwards. As it happens, the result of `test` is the value assigned to `sig`; I don't know whether you can count on that for testing purposes. If that's sufficient, you can do this (assuming you have Tcl 8.5; for 8.4 you need a helper procedure instead of the `apply` term):

```
source first.tcl
trace add execution test leave {apply {{cmd code result op} {
    # Copy the result of [test] to the global sig variable
    global sig
    set sig $result
}}}
```

This intercepts (just like with aspect-oriented programming) the result of `test` and saves it to the *global* `sig` variable. What it doesn't do though is correct for the problem in the tested code: the assignment is to a variable that goes away immediately after.

---

If you're doing lots of testing, consider using the tcltest to do the work. That's the package that is used to test Tcl itself, and it lets you write a test of the result of executing a script very easily:

```
# Setup of test harness
package require tcltest
source first.tcl

# The tests
tcltest::test test-1.1 {check if larger} -body {
    test 10
} -result 1
tcltest::test test-1.2 {check if smaller} -body {
    test 5
} -result 0

# Produce the final report
tcltest::cleanupTests
```

Comment: Thanks Donal Fellow can u elaborate the first part little more :)

Comment: @made_in_india Only if you give me some clue about which part needs elaboration. The range of possible things gets wide very quickly, so I can't just tell you everything; there's too much! Narrow down to what you're really looking for and I'll clarify just that part.

Comment: Fellow : thank u, I want to catch the value for $sig .. Is it possible to do with trace and apply. Can you give an example for the sample script of question

Comment: Tsnk u Donal , the script worked , but what if some other variable in proc test some other variable is being intialized after sig eg  proc test {a} {
   if {$a < 10} {
      set sig 0
   } else {
      set sig 1
   }  set sig2 2
}

Comment: @made_in_india That's the core limitation of the code. You _can't_ see changes to local variables with it. Nor will those changes to local variables persist after the procedure returns. (In fact, those are the same issue: if it persisted, you'd be able to find it and see it.)

Comment: If you use Tcl's introspection capabilities to poke inside (e.g., step-tracing the `test` procedure, or rewriting the body so that the variables persist) then you're interfering much more extensively and may well change the behavior of what you're trying to test. In short, you _can't_ do exactly what you want. If `sig` was a global variable, it would be much easier to test as its value would be meaningful at the point when you're trying to test it. (Local vars do not exist at all after the procedure finishes.)